# two divs not align horizontally

Tags: html, css

I just designed a simple sign-in form to practice CSS and HTML but I can't align 2 divs horizontally to input my name and surname.

Actually, I can't understand why if I apply a width of 50% they are stuck on top of each other and if I apply 49% width they are perfectly horizontally aligned as I want.

MY CSS (child width 50%):

I'm expecting with the child property set to 50% they should take 50% of the parent space.. but actually not, why?
what I'm doing wrong, why have to reduce the width to 49% to align them horizontally

see my image 50% width:
[image: wrong]

I want them aligned side by side like here:

[image: ok effect]

```css
.title{
    padding: 1vh;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2vh;
}

.wrapper{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}


.parent{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}

.child{
    width: 50%; <--------- HERE THE ISSUE
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">

        <div class="center">
            <h1 class="title">Sign Up New User</h1>

            <form class="submit_form">

                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="parent">
                        <div class="child">
                            <label for="Name">Name:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="Name" name="fname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="child">
                            <label for="Surname">Surname:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="Surname" name="fsurname" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex-box to achieve this,

I have added this in `parent`,

```
display: flex ; 
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly ;
```

You also have to remove  `width: 50%;` from the `.child` class and add the following `CSS`,

```
display:flex ; 
align-items:center;
justify-content:center ; 
flex-direction:column;
margin: 4px;
```

Now you can add further `CSS` as you want.

```css
.title{
    padding: 1vh;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2vh;
}

.wrapper{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}


.parent{
    background-color: red;
    display:flex ; 
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-evenly ; 
}

.child{
    display:flex ; 
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center ; 
    flex-direction:column;
    margin:4px ; 
}
```

```html
<body class="body">

        <div class="center">
            <h1 class="title">Sign Up New User</h1>

            <form class="submit_form">

                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="parent">
                        <div class="child">
                            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="Name" name="fname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="child">
                            <label for="Surname">Surname:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="Surname" name="fsurname" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly this should help. First what you want to do is understand what Flex is in html, [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) first helped me to understand flex.

So you want to add `display: flex;` to your container/`.parent` to tell the script that the container is a flex element. After that you should add  `text-align: center;` to center the text inside the `.parent`. Finnaly, add `justify-content: space-evenly;` so this way all of the items inside the `.parent` are spaced evenly from each other.

Also a lot of the things that you put in `.child` I removed becasue they where unnecessary to achieve what you are going for. I did add `margin: 5px;` just to make it look more visually appealing.

Your finished code should look like this

```css
        .title{
        padding: 1vh;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 2vh;
    }
    
    .wrapper{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    
    .parent{
        display: flex;
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    .child{
      margin: 5px;
    }
```

```html
 

    <body class="body">
    
            <div class="center">
                <h1 class="title">Sign Up New User</h1>
    
                <form class="submit_form">
    
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="parent">
                            <div class="child">
                                <label for="Name">Name:</label><br>
                                <input type="text" id="Name" name="fname">
                            </div>
                            <div class="child">
                                <label for="Surname">Surname:</label><br>
                                <input type="text" id="Surname" name="fsurname" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                </form>
            </div>
    
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be close to your desired result, I added some CSS to match the posted HTML.

Each `input` is centered in a box half of the container with `flex: 1`, so there is no need to set `width` in the code.

You can add more `child` field here, and the layout will scale naturally.

Example:

```css
.title {
  padding: 1vh;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2vh;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  color: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <h1 class="title">Sign Up New User</h1>

  <form class="submit_form">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
          <label for="Name">Name:</label><br />
          <input type="text" id="Name" name="fname" />
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <label for="Surname">Surname:</label><br />
          <input type="text" id="Surname" name="fsurname" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```